# How do I return these JSON objects to my browser instead of the console

Tags: node.js, express

Im receiving and displaying some JSON objects in /hello as seen below:

```
app.get('/hello' , (req, res) => {
  client
    .search('leather couch')
    .then((listings) => {
      // filtered listings (by price)
      console.log("got here");
      listings.forEach((listing) =>  console.log(listing));

    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.error(err);
    });
});
```

instead of console.logging each listing im trying to return these json objects in the browser!

I tried looking it up but can't seem to find the right wording to my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the response object to send to the browser.

There are several ways to that,

- res.send(jsonObject);
- res.json(jsonObject);
- res.status(statusCode).json(jsonObject);
  Take a look at the [api reference](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res).

So your approach can be

```
app.get('/hello' , (req, res) => {
  client
    .search('leather couch')
    .then((listings) => {
      // filtered listings (by price)
      return res.status(200).json(listing);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.error(err);
    });
});
```

Here, after grabbing the database result, we send it to the client instead of displaying in the console.

Comment: Thanks for the response! this worked . Although I think you meant to type .json(listings) right? Also, how does the code know to iterate through each listing without the forEach? Im not understanding how it understood to iterate thru all the listings without the forEach

Comment: in other words, why wouldn't this work : return listings.forEach((listing) =>  res.json(listing));    this seems to only return one JSON object but im not sure why

Comment: When the first element is reached in for each loop, it sent the first one. Because the server gets the res.json(data), it immediately leaves the method and not executing any further.

Comment: Thanks for the help @Shams Nahid

Comment: Glad to help you. Will you please flag the answer as accepted then, by clicking the check mark on the left side of the answer?

Answer (score 0):

You can send a success JSON response like this -

> `res.json({yourKey : yourValue});`

Where res is the response object you receive with request. For more details refer this [expressjs](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.json) doc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use res.send() to return

```
app.get('/hello' , (req, res) => {
   client
   .search('leather couch')
   .then((listings) => {
       res.send({ list: listings });
   })
   .catch((err) => {
       console.error(err);
   });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the response although this solution only gave me back one listing and then threw an error

Comment: I've changed the code now it'll work fine.@CarlosHerrera

Comment: Thanks @Sumit Kumar. Appreciate your help